# Post file issue of Python wsgiref simple_server

Tags: python, simplehttpserver, falconframework

I'm writing a WSGI Python web server app with falcon framework.
And I use `wsgiref.simple_server` for local test.

It works smoothly until I want to test posting a file to my server.
My code is likes below:

```
  def on_post(self, req, resp):
    """ handle files upload by user """

    file_path = 'user_upload_file_' + str(uuid.uuid4())

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as user_upload_file:

        while True:
            chunk = req.stream.read(4096)

            if not chunk:
                break

            user_upload_file.write(chunk)

     # ... give back response ...
```

Once I post with a file to my simple_server hosted app, it seems to hang on the line of `req.stream.read()`.

But if I host my app with uWSGI, this piece of code works well.

Is this issue has something to do with simple_server?